# Re-arrange div boxes in desktop

Tags: css

I have divs stacked like the following for mobile:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want to arrange it to look like this when it's desktop (ignore the spacing, I just want to get them in the correct position first:

```
       +-------------+
       |      B
       |
  C    +-------------+
       |      D
       |
-------+--+----------+
          |
   A      |     E
          |
          +
```

I tried with `display: flex` and specifying the `order`, but I can't get `D` to be positioned under `B` but the right of `C`. Is it still possible to use `flex` for this? I also have `neat` v2 in my app.

This is my current code:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;

  .C {
    order: 1;
    @include grid-column(2);
  }

  .B {
    order: 2;
    @include grid-column(10);
  }

  .A {
    @include grid-column(7);
    order: 3;
  }

  .D {
    @include grid-column(10);
    order: 4;  
  }

  .E {
    @include grid-column(5);
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 0):

You could just use JavaScript to test for the dimensions of a screen.  If the dimensions of a mobile device are being used, display the divs like it is now. If the dimension of a PC are being use, just do something like `position: absolute;` for your divs. I am not sure if there is an easier solution, but I hope this works for you.